# No me toma system("cls") ni system("pause") en lenguaje C

Tags: c

despues de hacer un realloc()...Mi codigo se salta dichas lineas, tengo importada tanto la libreria  como .. estaba funcionando bien y de pronto no tomo mas esas lineas. alguno sabe que puede ser? desde ya muchas gracias!

```
int agregarUsuario(stCelda **ArrUsers, int validos, stCelda nueva)
{

    (*ArrUsers) = (stCelda *)realloc((*ArrUsers),sizeof(stCelda)*validos+1);

    (*ArrUsers)[validos] = nueva;
    validos++;

    return validos;
}
```

---

Si, lo estoy guardando .c, es mas, no me tira error ni nada. solo en una funcion en especifico no me funcionan esos comandos, no me tira ningun error ni nada. simplemente no limpia la pantalla.

Comment: Lee [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), luego edita la pregunta agregando el código al que te refieres.